# Ubuntu GCE does not see new system disk space after disk resize

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-16.04, google-compute-engine

I have an Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS GCE instance.
I increased system disk space (from 20 GB to 30 GB) but after GCE restart, if I run

```
df -h
```

I still get 20GB on disk size.

In the past, on Ubuntu GCE Instances, after the instance restart, the System automatically saw new disk space.

Also in the documentation I read:

> "Alternatively, instances that use most recent versions of Public
>   Images can automatically resize their partitions and file systems
>   after a system reboot. The SUSE Linux Enterprise Server (SLES) public
>   images are the only images that do not support this feature."

So, what is the problem?
What can I do to get the new space?

Comment: Check the console logs and review what is reported during reboot for the resize operation. I wrote an article on how Google resizes Debian. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-debian-9-resize-root-file-system/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute:

```
$ sudo lsblk
```

```
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1 30G
```

If you receive the message:

> **The filesystem is already 5242619 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!**

Sorry, I believe that you can't resize the disk using **resize2fs**.

So, I know two alternatives that you can follow.

**Alternative 1 -** Attach another one disk in the VM.

**Alternative 2 -** Create a new disk from a snapshot of the original disk. 
Steps to create a disk from a snapshot:

1. Stop the machine (not necessary but it is safe)
2. Take a snapshot

```
gcloud beta compute disks snapshot <disk_name> --project=<project_id> --snapshot-names=snapshot-1 --zone=<zone> --storage-location=us
```

3. Create a new machine from that snapshot